# Page css doesnt refresh within javascript function

Tags: css, ajax, google-chrome, visibility

my first question here so be gentle :).

I have this issue with changing css of elements and their refresh. I am createing a webforms application with ajax requests. My problem is that when somone chooses a report from a tree view it should display a gif with loading sign and after data is recieved it should display it. Its working fine on firefox and opera but not on ie, chore or safari. Here is the code:

This the method that is launched when someone clicks a tree node
    this.hideElements();
    var id = node.getId().substr(2);

```
var client = new CAjaxClient();
var data;

client.addParameter(new CKeyValuePair('ReportID', id));

client.postCallBack('/ajaxpages/Reports.aspx', 'GetReportFilters', this.dataRecieved);

filterGenerator.setReportID(id);
```

This the method hideElements()

```
$('#FiltersContainer').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('#ActionsContainer').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('#loadingDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
$("input[id$='Date']").parent().css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

This the ajax postBack method

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
$('#FiltersContainer').css('visibility', 'visible');
$('#ActionsContainer').css('visibility', 'visible');
$('#loadingDiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');
var data = eval(this.responseText);
filterGenerator.processFiltersData(data);
```

Data and everything is returned in order its just that in the request time the browser is like frozen and when the data returns css state is of that at the end of the whole process. Loading div is never shown. I tried also forcing redraw with domelement.style changing but no effect. When I execute the code in chrome debugger line by line everything goes perfectly. Please help if you can.

Html code(vio:TreeView is our own ASP control):

```
<div id="pageHeader" style="display:inline-block">

        <div id="headerImageDiv" style="float:left; margin-left:15px; margin-top:5px;">
            <img src="style/default/printerLarge.png" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div id="pageTitleDiv" style="float:left">
            <span style="display:block; margin-top:20px;margin-left:10px;color:#78b4bb; font-size:20px;">Reports And Analyses</span>
            <span style="display:block; margin-top:20px;margin-left:10px;font-size:18px;">Select a report</span>   
        </div>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="mainPane" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
        <div id="readerTreeContainer" style="float:left;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-right:none; border-width:1px; overflow : auto;width:300px;height:auto; background-color:white;">
             <vio:TreeView ID="TreeView" runat="server"
                     Width="298" Height="500"
                     ActionListener="ReportsGeneralListener"
                     ActionListenerScript="ReportsGeneralTree.js"
                     GlobalTreeviewName="reportsTreeview">
             </vio:TreeView>

        </div>

        <div id="FiltersContainer" style="position:relative;visibility:hidden;float:left;border-top-style:solid;border-right-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-left:solid 1px; border-width:2px; overflow : auto;width:30%;height:500px; background-color:#dbdae4;">
            <div id="filterColumnOne" style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;border-right:solid 1px;border-left:none;">

            </div>
                <div id="filterColumnTwo" style="float:left;width:49%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div id="loadingDiv" style="z-index:10;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin: -35% 0 0 -35%;z-index:100001;height:316px;width:396px;">
                <div  style="position:relative;display:block">
                     <img src="style/default/loading.gif" alt="" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:-1;"/>
                    <span style="display:block;text-align:center;padding-top:80px;font-size:25px;font-weight:bold;">Loading Report</span>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="ActionsContainer" style="visibility:hidden;float:left;border-left-style:none;border-top-style:solid;border-right-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-width:2px; overflow : auto;width:200px;height:200px; background-color:#abe9e7;">
              <div style="display:block;border-bottom:solid 1px;height:50%">
                  <div style="position:relative; height:100%;">
                      <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%; height:72px;margin: -35px 0 0 -35%;">
                          <img src="style/default/document.png" alt="" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;"/>
                          <button type="button" style="margin-top:18%;height:30px;" onclick="print();">Print</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div style="display:block;border:none;height:49%;">
                  <div style="position:relative; height:100%;">
                      <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%; height:72px;margin: -35px 0 0 -35%;">
                          <img src="style/default/application_pdf.png" alt="" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;height:72px;"/>
                          <button type="button" style="margin-top:18%;height:30px;">PDF</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .hide and .show instead. They work cross-browser.

See the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

I think your problem was:

```
<div stuff I'm hiding>
    <div loading screen>
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mL8eT/) for a working demo of what you provided. I removed the inline visibility:hidden from the styles (I'd suggest you split into a CSS file, it's making it unreadable) and took the loading div from inside the div you were hiding.

Comment: Tried it and the effect is the same

Comment: maybe share your html source or post a jsfiddle?

Comment: posted html code, never used jsfiddle so dont really know how to use it and i dont know if i can since i am working on a ASP.NET app

Comment: No that is not the problem. I changed and tested obviously but no change. Problem is that between the request to the server with ajax and data recieved the browser is like frozen. Cant click on any button and so on. Maybe ill post my ajax request and someone will see sth.

Comment: I resolved the issue, problem was that the ajax request didnt have a async flag on, and i was asured by someone who made it that it was. And since it worked on firefox and opera i didnt check it. So sorry for trouble and thanks